# Time travel book

Tags: story-identification, novel

This was a long time ago, so it’s not the best description of the book. I remember these two boys were friends, and one day, they find out all their teachers and parents are part of a secret organisation which has a time machine.

The father of the main one of the two boys isn’t around, as he stole a time machine and is wanted.

And I think that someone tried to stop the assassination of the archduke of Austria.

Comment: You should have a look at this [guide](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info) on story id questions; it might jog your memory on some more detail.

Answer (score 4):

Could it be *[Day of the Assassins](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1138929)* by Johnny O'Brien, from 2009?

Per Goodreads:

> Jack Christie and his best friend, Angus, find themselves at the center of a momentous event that will shape history for decades to come. Their dilemma: Should they intervene? Their problem: Can they survive? Join Jack on a dangerous chase from the dockyards of England to the rain-sodden trenches of the First World War. Will he escape the evil authorities who believe in the mysterious Vigil Imperative?

The [publisher's Web site](https://www.allenandunwin.com/browse/books/childrens/young-adult-fiction/Day-Of-The-Assassins-Johnny-OBrien-9781848770911) has a similar blurb, but also including:

> When teenager Jack Christie stumbles upon a time machine and a secret time-travelling society his life changes forever.